# Visual Studio Code - Process exit with code 134

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger, node-debugger

I'm facing an annoying issue in VSC. I cannot run and debug any code via NodeJs, because I keep getting the same error in title.

I have already reintall 2-3 times VSC and I did the same with NodeJS and the problem persists.
[image]

In terms of memory the computer is using 4.7MB of 7.5MB available.
[image]

I've followed this stack overflow thread: [node.exe exited with code 134 Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63012947/node-exe-exited-with-code-134-visual-studio)

But nothing worked.

How can I solve this issue, pls?

I have answered above.
Well, I am expecting that someone really tell me what to do to solve the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.exe exited with code 134 Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63012947/node-exe-exited-with-code-134-visual-studio)

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Comment: What happens when you run the script from the command line (outside vscode), using `node script_rstotal_rpeticao.js` ?  Which version of node ?

Comment: @Luuk 
run it from the cmd line in W: not the complete folder where I have the JS file

C:\Users\João Matos>node script_DoWhile
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\João Matos\script_DoWhile'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
Node.js v18.18.0

Comment: @JoaoMatos: Sorry, it is unclear what you actually did.  With my previous comment I did mean [Run Node.js scripts from the command line](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/command-line/run-nodejs-scripts-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing any custom configurations in your Node.js installation. To identify the files you need to delete, use the following commands:

For current user configurations:

```bash
npm config get userconfig
```

For global configurations:

```bash
npm config get globalconfig
```

Apply the changes with:

```bash
npm config edit
npm config --global edit
```

This will help you identify and remove any custom settings in your Node.js installation.

Comment: I don't have any custom configurations. Just install it as it is